# Laravel Models Where Clause With Relation and calculated Attributes

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel and I have two different models with Many to Many Relationship.

One of them has a calculated attribute

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Attendance\AttendanceSheet;
use App\Modules\Members\IO\Enums\DocumentationTypeEnum;
use App\Modules\Members\IO\Enums\GenderStatusEnum;
use App\Modules\Members\IO\Enums\MemberOriginEnum;
use App\Modules\Members\IO\Enums\MemberStatusEnum;
use App\Modules\Members\IO\Enums\MemberTypeEnum;
use App\Models\Tutor;
use App\Service\Member\CategoriesHelper;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;


class Member extends Model
{
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'number', 'name', 'lastname', 'birthdate' ... [some other fields], 
    ];


    protected $appends = [
        'age', 'category'
    ];

  
    public function attendanceSheets()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(AttendanceSheet::class, 'attendance_sheets_members');
    }


    public function getCategoryAttribute()
    {
        $categoriesHelper = new CategoriesHelper();

        $birthDate = date_create($this->birthdate);
        return $categoriesHelper->getCategoryRecursively($birthDate);
    }

}
```

So in my manager I'm trying to have my attendance sheets with all members but having some particular fields (one of them is this calculated Attribute)

If I do

```
        $data = AttendanceSheet::where('id', $sheetId)->with('members')->first();
```

Everything is shown ok, but members has all fields (Database and calculated attributes)

but If I do

```
        $data = AttendanceSheet::where('id', $sheetId)->with('members:number,name,category')->first();
```

throws me an error because category is not in my table.

How can I solve it? thanks

Comment: Try a get(). `->with('members')->get([])->first()` with the array in the get being the list of fields you want. If there are same fields in both, you'll get a "blah field is ambiguous" message, so just prepend the field name with the table name.

Comment: MySQL can not help with appended attributes. But you can try with [transform](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-transform) function over returned collection.

Comment: The properties in `$appends` will be appended, but only if it has the data it needs. Per the duplicate answer, try `with('members:number,name,birthdate')`. Since your accessor references `$this->birthdate` that property must be present.